# Using LocalHost IIS over Express; custom based

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I have been in the situation where my rest of the team is using IIS express, where as I feel more comfortable with proper IIS.

I know I can change project file and direct to the IIS. However it comes with the limitation.

I cannot push project file changes to git because it will affect others.

Is there any nicest way to handle such thing so that I use IIS where as the rest  is still on IISExpress?

Comment: I don't know if it works, but you could move the IIS-specific settings into a separate .csproj file that is included in the canonical csproj file by way of `<import />`, and then configure Git to ignore any changes to that file (to not push and don't overwrite on pull either).

Answer (score 2):

In your project's properties (right click in solution explorer, properties), go to the 'Web' tab and uncheck"Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)", this way the changes will be kept in the user settings projectName.csproj.user file

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't have a bunch of url-based dependencies the solution is easy -- just configure IIS manually to point at the folder on a different port than IIS.

Debugging is a little trickier to kick off -- you will need to run Visual Studio as administrator and then attach to the IIS process.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about how he can save his `.csproj` settings for IIS locally without pushing them out to Git.